# how to find the GridViewCommandColumn that set ShowSelectCheckbox=true in aspxgridview.columns?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, devexpress

i need to done in programmatic and i have no idea on it. So i need to use loop to search all the  columns? For example:

```
  GridViewCommandColumn a= new GridViewCommandColumn();
  a.showselectcheckbox=true;
  aspxgridview1.columns.find(a);
```

Comment: You could use a big continues if statement like if(a=checked&b=checked)

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the **required Column** via the **ASPxGridView.Columns** collection in the following manner:

by FieldName/Caption/Name:

```
GridViewCommandColumn commandColumn = (GridViewCommandColumn)ASPxGridViewInstance.Columns["#"];
```

by VisibleIndex:

```
GridViewCommandColumn commandColumn = (GridViewCommandColumn)ASPxGridViewInstance.Columns[0];
```

Comment: GridViewCommandColumn using custom HeaderTemplate that only contain checkbox. So (GridViewCommandColumn)ASPxGridViewInstance.Columns["#"]; will not found it.

Comment: Would you clarify the task you are trying to accomplish and share more ASPX markup?

Comment: i'm try to develop a custom control inherit from aspxgridview and i want to create a new boolean properties to control whether show the selectall checkbox on the GridViewCommandColumn to select all the row in page.

Comment: GridViewCommandColumn checkboxcolumn = new GridViewCommandColumn() { HeaderTemplate = new checkboxcolumnheadertemplate(this.ClientInstanceName), ShowSelectCheckbox = true, VisibleIndex = 0 };
                    this.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxcolumn);

i able to add column but now i wish to find that column.